# Add dynamic variable to onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `onclick` event that loads up an iframe. I need to be able to dynamically change part of the URL that is in the `onclick` even event. What's the best possible way to do this? The part I need to dynamically replace I highlighted below as ****variable here***.

```
var ****variable here*** = '343h343432e';

<button type="button" id="load_2" class="btn btn-info" onClick="document.getElementById('attri_map').height = '520';document.getElementById('attri_map').src='https://example.com/****variable here***';document.getElementById('load_2').style.display = 'none';">Click to Load</button>

<iframe id='attri_map' width='100%'  height="0" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Why don't you instead of using a variable name and its value use a key/value pair object `var varName = {key: "urlPart", data: {anything else}}`

Comment: don't use var please try it

Comment: it will make the variable global and you can edit that outside in whole script

Comment: Unnecessary global variables are bad practice, especially in javascript where they can have infinite scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good opportunity for you to extract out the JavaScript, as inline isn't really good practice.

Remove the `onClick` event on your element in your HTML, then you can do:

(I've also put `attri_map` into a variable to remove the overhead of re-querying the DOM for the same element.)

```
var variable = "example";

document.getElementById("load_2").onclick = function () {
    var attrMap = document.getElementById('attri_map');
    attrMap.height = '520';
    attrMap.src='https://example.com/' + variable;
    document.getElementById('load_2').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the direction I was looking for. I knew there was a MUCH better way to do this than what I had. Your changes worked perfectly. Appreciate the extra clean up too!

Comment: @jonmrich No problems, glad I could help.